# custom post type or taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I'm working on a real-estate site where I need to create a profile for each **agent**, the initial view when you click on **view agents** would be to list them alphabetically, ideally from a dropdown you could select a **region** to view all the **agents** from that **region**, or chose a **language** to view all the **agents** who speak a given **language**.

My thinking is **Agent** would be a custom post type, **region** and **language** would be a taxonomy.

The listing of **agents** would then be created by showing many posts, just only showing limited details, then when clicked act as a single post, with more details shown?

Does this seem like the best way to go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That Sounds about right, I'm just about to finish similar project with the same base (post type, taxonomies) structure, so here are a few notes to get you going:

- To enable your "view agents" make
  sure when you register agents post
  type that you set has_archive to true
  or use string as archive slug which
  will make your life much easier.
- When registering custom taxonomies
  make sure to set `rewrite` to `true`.
- Create a custom template
  taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php for each of
  your custom taxonomies (even if they
  both show the same thing, trust me on
  this one) this will save you a lot of
  time.
- On your "view agents" template file (`archive-agents.php`) Use [wp_dropdown_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories)
  function to generate your region and
  language dropdowns.
- And last create your
  single-agents.php template file to
  display the full information of the
  agent.

Comment: Cannot argue with the points you have made there. I remember my first custom post type set-up. Its very confusing at first but after you've done a few its easy peasy :)

Comment: Thanks should be an interesting weekend ahead, if anyone else has any other tips they're greatly appreciated.